# c++ function not calling

Tags: c++, function

I've been trying to write a programme that can solve a sudoku. It doesn't work though (yet) and I'm not sure why. The full code is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_we6hUmPkaMSVl5WEdxWi1MWms/view?usp=sharing).

Th part that's giving me trouble is this:

```
int eliminate_3x3(){
    for(int top =0; top>9; top+=3){
        std::cout << "eliminate 3x3 is function properly" << std::endl;
        //Based on the previous line, I'd expect to see that message pop up 3 times every time 'main'
        //calls this function, but it is never shown.
        for(int left =0; left>9; left+=3){
            for(int column =0; column > 3; column++){
                for(int row=0; row > 3; row++){
                    int current_value = MyArray[top+column][left+row];
                    std::cout << current_value << std::endl;
                    if(current_value != 0){
                        for(int column2 =0; column2 > 3; column2++){
                            for(int row2 =0; row2 > 3; row2++){
                                possibility_array[top+column2][left+row2][current_value-1] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        possibility_array[top+column][left+row][current_value-1] = current_value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, it simply doesn't do anything at all (or maybe it isn't being called properly by `main`. If anyone could tell me why, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

I apologise in advance if my use of for loops is a problem for some, I'm still relatively new to C++ and that was the solution that seemed best to me.

Comment: *"or maybe it isn't being called properly by main"* Maybe. But we can't *see* `main()`.

Comment: Also, none of your loops will do anything. They all start out with `>` conditions that should be `<`. if `top = 0`, then `top > 9` will *never* be true.

Comment: And now I feel like a moron. I changed so many other things trying to fix it, I can't believe it was something so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first loop

```
 for(int top =0; top>9; top+=3)
```

the `top >9`condition is not true when top is initialized, so the loop will not run. If this isn't a typo I suggest you look up C++ for loop syntax.

I believe you want it to be `top<9` and you also need to change it for the nested loops.

Comment: It was indeed a typo. How I made it so many times in one function is beyond me. Thanks for pointing that out.